# Is the correct value being shown? PHP

Tags: php, html, html-select

I successfully echoed out the values that I wanted between the  tags but value isn't being recognized which I don't understand, I did a test elsewhere and the value is stored.

This is what I am trying to do where $row[1] displays in the drop down but when selected, no value is stored.

```
echo '<option value="'.$row[1].'">'."$row[1]".'</option>';
```

alternatively

```
$val = $row[1];
// or
$val = "$row[1]";

       echo '<option value="'.$val.'">'.
       $row[1].
       '</option>';
```

This is my test which works

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

$something = $_POST['soption'];
$hey = "hey";
}
?>
<html>
<form method="post">
<select name="soption">
<?php
$you = "somevalue";
$some = '<option value="'.$you.'">'.
       "something".
       '</option>';
echo $some;
?>
<option value="else">real</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="test">
</form>
<?php echo isset($something)? $something:""; ?>
<?php echo isset($hey)? $hey:""; ?>
</html>
```

Comment: what is stored in `$row[1]`?

Comment: $row[1] has assorted strings, they display in the drop down select menu, but they don't appear to have values eg. value=""

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be a problem here, I tested your code in my local server and it displayed both $something and $hey in the echo.

The proper syntax for `'."$row[1]".'` is `'.$row[1].'` though if your original enclosing quotes under echo were single quotes.

Comment: Yeah I was saying the test works, so I'm wondering why the first part doesn't which successfully pulls the database entries and displays them as options in the dropdown select box but when you select any of them it appears that they are "empty" eg. no value so the query isn't stored in the database. Thank you for your help.

Comment: What database? You didn't show any of that code in here.

Comment: That isn't the issue, the database is being pulled properly in order to populate the drop down menu, the problem is, it is as if the options do not have values because when I try to select any of them, no value is stored so when I try to complete the query, nothing is stored. However if I manually set something equal to the select name="" value that would have been defined by the option selected, the query goes through.

Comment: You only showed part of the code for your first problem. Maybe you could show it in its entirety so I can see where the value isn't showing up?

Comment: I appreciate your interest but I don't know how I can be any more clear. I am using the same value  $row[1] for both the <option value="$row[1]">$row[1]</option>, this is not direct, I'm abandoning this idea anyway, a drop down box of 20 items is pretty ridiculous

Comment: What? No it's not. The day column for any date form has 31. Try using the successful form instead.

Comment: I'm being an idiot, I don't understand what I'm missing. $row[1] = $row[1] is it not? I am using both of these values to generate the strings placed in between the columns of value="$row[1]" and <option>"$row[1]"</option>. Since the drop down select menu exists, that must mean that the query is successful and indeed shows all of the database entries. But the left $row[1] does not seem to have a value. I can post code, but I don't think I need to, I defined the problem up there. I do appreciate your time sincerely there are a lot of questions asked here.